# Swipe to delete UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios

How can I delete a UITableView row on swipe? I know the question has been asked, but I get only errors. Here's the code:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle 
    forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // If row is deleted, remove it from the list.
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
         NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
         [tableDataSource removeObjectAtIndex:row];      
    }
}
```

But nothing happens. I would appreciate if you write code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

reload table after removing the row.

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: OMG! And that was that easy! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 45):

Better is just to delete the selected row, not reload all the table:

```
 [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

Comment: the line above gave me an error, so this (pretty much the same) works nicely.

`[myTable deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];`